# AJAX request gives 'undefined index' error in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm getting `undefined index(return data)` from this AJAX call. What am I doing wrong here? Please correct me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#something').click(function() {
        edit(1, 'abc', 'xyz');
    });

    function edit(id, column, text) {
        $.ajax({  
            url: "edit.php",  
            method: "POST",  
            data: {
                id: id, 
                text: text, 
                column: column
            },  
            dataType: "text",  
            success: function(data) {  
                 console.log(data);  
            }  
        });      
    }
});
```

edit.php

```
echo $_POST["id"];
```

I'm getting this in the console:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: id in **C:\xampp\htdocs\datatable\edit.php** on line **2**

Comment: That error means the problem is in your PHP code, not the JS. Check the `edit.php` file on line 2.

Comment: on line 2 this code is there echo $_POST["id"]

Comment: is the path to `edit.php` correct? is: are there more than one `edit.php` files to which you are trying to POST information to by any chance?

Comment: @RamRaider, yeh everything is there in the same folder

Comment: Put this `var_dump($_POST);` in edit.php. comment `echo $_POST["id"];` then paste here the result.

Comment: use POSTMAN tools if you want to test http post. just send raw json match with your params. {"id":"1", "column":"2", "text":"this is my text"}. then set header content-type : application/json. choose method POST

Comment: @vher2, i'm getting array(0) { }

Comment: That's the reason `$_POST["id"]` is undefined. The data was not sent to edit.php. Can you check if the data is being sent, in the network tab of your dev tool. click the link then check the Headers, from there you will see the Form data that was sent.

Comment: i have specified method as post but post is not working i'm getting data through get? if any one knows the reason behind it please answer here

Answer (score 1):

Try using

> Type: "POST"

instead of

> Method: "POST"

```
   ...$.ajax({  
        url: "edit.php",  
        type: "POST",  
        data: {
            id: id, 
            text: text, 
            column: column
        }.....
```

Does it still class as a GET request with this? I think this is because of your jQuery version.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of the way you wrote the json array keys.

Try to use double quotes for the keys from data json, like this:

```
data:{"id":id, "text":text, "column":column}
```

or use different names for variables and keys.

Comment: Hi! Should I remove this answer ?

Comment: @RamRaider, sir in xhr tab i'm getting some thing like this http://localhost/datatable/edit.php?id=40&text=Line+1.%0A+++++++++++Line+2+is+to+the+right+of+line+1.%0A+++++++++++Line+3+aligns+with+line+2.%0A&column=description

Comment: This means that your data is sent to edit.php. In the xhr tab you should check the response for that request. If edit.php contains var_dump($_POST), then you should see all your data sent with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the url : "edit.php" has not to access in your server.

Normaly, if you are in your server local ; so you change your url to :

"http://localhost/yourproject/edit.php".

```
  $.ajax({  
            url:"http://localhost/yourproject/edit.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{id:id, text:text, column:column},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data){  
                 console.log(data);  
            }  
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, you can add content-type json if you want to get it with PHP $_POST. I'm not sure about this but it works in my Angular

```
function edit(id, column, text) {
    $.ajax({  
        url: "edit.php",  
        method: "POST",  
        data: {
            id: id, 
            text: text, 
            column: column
        },  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {  
             console.log(data);  
        }  
    });      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code

```
/* start */ 
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#something').click(function() {

    var sendData = {
        url : '1',
        method : 'abc',
        column : 'xyz'
    };

    edit(sendData);

});

function edit(id, column, text) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "edit.php",
        data: sendData,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });   
} 
});

/* end */
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JQuery are you using? Try changing

```
method: "POST",
```

to

```
type: "POST",
```